# SVN: Is it possible to have a single file appear in multiple folders?

Tags: svn

Take a single file and somehow share it across a bunch of other folders

e.g.
Myfile is part of MyFirstFolder and Myfile is part of MySecondFolder

Then if anyone updates Myfile, the other folder will also receive the newer file version on updating/refreshing

Answer (score 4):

You can use svn:externals property to reference the file in `MySecondFolder`:

```
svn propedit svn:externals "../MyFirstFolder/MyFile MyFile" .
```

See more about svn:externals: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html